# "Default boot device missing or boot failed" after erasing GPT

Tags: boot, partitioning, gpt

I wanted to install Ubuntu with dual-boot but the installer couldn't find the windows partition.

I read online that erasing the GPT could help. I did so with gdisk (wich told me that I have MBR protective and GPT present). After that I cannot load windows and Ubuntu still tell me that windows is not installed.

When I try to boot, I get a message from the motherboard that says "Default boot device missing or boot failed".

gdisk now say that I have MBR protective and no GPT.

I tried all the boot list, nothing works.

I'm scared I cannot recover my data... :/

Comment: GPT or GUID partition table means all partitions inside that table are now gone. At least if you format a single partition you only lose the data on that partition, you wiped all partitions stored on that (gpt) table.  We don't know what backup strategy you have implemented...  but `testdisk` may help - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: Windows only boots in UEFI boot mode from gpt partitioned drives. But you have to boot Windows installer in UEFI boot mode to install in UEFI/gpt configuration. Microsoft has required UEFI/gpt on all new pre-installed systems since Windows 8 relased in 2012. So all hardware since then is UEFI. Users can install in 35 year old BIOS/MBR mode if desired, but that was available primarily for Windows 7 BIOS compatibility on newer hardware.

Answer (score 0):

"MBR Protective" is a part of the GPT, but since you've deleted the GPT partitioning, you will need to reinstall then restore from your last backup.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to recover partitions.
You need to turn off "legacy boot" in your BIOS. (you should have done this before installing; then you would not have had your problems). 
By allowing only UEFI boot, the Ubuntu live disk will boot in this mode.

EDIT: Your bios is not guaranteed to call it 'legacy boot'. You want to allow only EFI/UEFI boot (they mean  the same thing). Legacy boot is sometimes called CSM. Learn more: [Difference between Legacy BIOS and UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993269/difference-between-legacy-bios-and-uefi) )

Then, try  this: 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370121

Be very careful deleting partitions or partition tables. It's worth while researching what you are about to do, rather than trusting advice, or misunderstanding it. Or ask here.

Comment: I already tried something with gdisk, I did a backup and installed it, it nows says that the gpt partition is there. But I still can't boot. I'll try what you say. Thanks a lot