# Windows 10 in LEGACY mode + dual boot Ubuntu Studio 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, 20.04, grub-legacy

I have Windows 10 installed in Legacy mode (upgraded from Win7) and I want to add Ubuntu Studio 20.04 (dual boot). Is it safe just to start installation disk and allow Ub.Studio to install itself along Win10 **and** create partitions from within the installation programme? This is what I always did with Win 7 and I wonder if it won't destroy my Win10 this time. Most issues reported concern conflicts between Legacy and UEFI, but I have no UEFI Win10 installation ... so perhaps it could work again? I am afraid to risk losing Windows though ...

Answer (score 1):

You can convert Windows 10 to UEFI through command prompt. I have tried this and it worked perfectly for me. After converting Windows 10 to UEFI you won't have conflict issues between UEFI and BIOS.

### How to convert Windows to UEFI

This will only work if you have windows 10 version 1703 or higher.

1. Enter windows recovery environment by holding `shift` and selecting restart.
2. In Troubleshoot-->Advanced open command prompt with your admin account.
3. type `mbr2gpt /validate` and press `enter`.
   [image: validate]
4. type `mbr2gpt /convert` and press `enter`.
   [image: convert]
5. Exit the cmd and select turn off the pc.
6. Power on and go to firmware setting by pressing `F2`.
7. Change the boot mode to UEFI
8. Save and exit (`F10`)

Comment: Thanks for this prompt! However, I had thought that having both systems in Legacy mode is safer in terms of possible conflicts between systems and should create an environment in which Ubuntu can install itself along with Windows smoothly ... Was I wrong?

Comment: Actually UEFI is much safer and higher in functionality.   
|
1. UEFI enables users to handle drives that are larger than 2 TB, while the old legacy BIOS couldn't handle large storage drives.  
|
2. UEFI supports more than 4 primary partitions with a GUID Partition Table.  
|
3. Computers who use UEFI firmware have faster booting process than the BIOS. Various optimizations and enhancement in the UEFI can help your system boot more quickly than it could before.

Comment: 4. UEFI supports secure startup, which means that the validity of the operating system can be checked to ensure that no malware tampers with the startup process.  
|
5. UEFI supports networking function in the UEFI firmware itself, which helps remote troubleshooting and UEFI configuration.  
|
6. UEFI has a simpler graphical user interface and also has much richer setup menus than legacy BIOS.

Comment: @ToSz If you BIOS you will run into a problem with partitioning. Read these. https://askubuntu.com/questions/993269/difference-between-legacy-bios-and-uefi 

https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/uefi-vs-bios.html 

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-UEFI-and-Legacy-Mode-which-we-need-to-choose-while-installing-the-OS