# Grub file problems upgrading from 32 to 64bit Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have a 64 bit machine but was running a 32 bit version of Ubuntu (dual boot) alongside Windows. I installed a 64 bit version from USB image but ended up in grub rescue. I have identified the right partition and folder for the grub file:
(hd0, msdos8)/boot/efi/grub
but it says it is still not found. Is this to do with architecture? It says boot/efi/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod not found

I am a complete beginner, grateful for any help

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! 32-bit Ubuntu was most likely using legacy BIOS mode but you seem to have installed the 64-bit version in UEFI mode. Can you check which of these two options are used by your Windows and BIOS? See also [Difference between Legacy BIOS and UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/q/993269/250300).

Comment: Thank you, I found a good solution using Boot Repair whilst running Ubuntu from the USB drive. Howtogeek.com/114884

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) Thanks for your response, let me mark this question as a duplicate of an existing one.